# How can I use a my customer_id (a string value) and avoid create new user for every new payment session in Stripe?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

In Stripe payments in every new payment session a new customer was created. I need to use the `current_id` from the logged in user.

Based on the official Stripe examples, I tried to replace the `customer_id` in the **Payment Activity** with my `customer_id` but it didn't work.

I expect to to proceed with a payment using the existing customer id and not everytime with a new one.

Comment: You would have to implement that on your backend server that is generating the ephemeral key. The Payment Session uses the customer that you generated the ephemeral key for, so your logic for authenticating the user of the app and deciding which Stripe customer object to use is where you'd need to look.

Comment: "... your logic for authenticating the user of the app and deciding which Stripe customer object to use is where you'd need to look. " I am sorry but I don't understand that. When do I need to look? Now, when a user logged in to the app receives a token from by backend (for authentication) and a stripe customer_id which was created by the backend. So, I need to use this customer_id and the ephemeral_key that I received (using the ephemeral_keys API) in order to proceed with the Charge Function. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, that sounds normal. The user logs in to your app, you create(or retrieve) a Stripe customer ID, and use that to create an ephemeral key the SDK can use to interact with that customer. When they check out, you can use the ID to charge them by calling the /v1/charges API with the customer ID you have. What specifically is blocking you? Do you have examples of code you've tried, errors you've got that you can edit into the question?

Comment: I fixed that. The main problem was that I had map 3 customers to the same email so there was a conflict. Thank you for your help.